# Can I block HTML elements system-wide?

Tags: firefox, browser, internet, html, hosts

I know there is a hosts file that allows me to block entire domains.

```
0.0.0.0 blockthissite.net
::      blockthssite.net
```

I'd like to block particular elements for a website.

I can do this today with one of a variety of ad blocking tools, like uBlock Origin. It will only work on the browser that I set up the rule with for the ad blocking tool and, even then, it's really easy for someone to get around the rule by disabling the extension.

Is there a hosts file or something more system-wide that I can do to block HTML elements on my Mac?

For instance, I'd like to block the footer page on this popular website from every browser.

```
www.amazon.com###navFooter
```

I'd like to administer this across an individual computer. I have a pi hole, but that only works with domains and doesn't have information on the html elements. For why is this a concern, I'd like to consistently block some html elements across browsers

Comment: Not without using a browser plugin, no.

Comment: Are there applications that work system wide?

Comment: No. your OS doesn't try to be a browser, so it is never even asked when the browser wants to go to a url. the DNS name resolution is the only thing it can see. about the only thing you could use is a WebApplicationFirewall (a WAF) but I don't think you'll find one for desktop use.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: So what you should have done is [edit] the question to include the additional information you have in the comments. That would have put your question in the reopen queue.

Comment: Note: Adding random comments does not "bump" your question.

Comment: Thanks! Would you prefer for me to add the context from my comments into this post or the earlier post? Appreciate your help https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill

Comment: Definitely stay with this post, as you already put up a bounty. If asked, add more info to this post.

Comment: A solution for the browser only is an add-on like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) with for example [this userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/25448-block-sites/code).

Comment: The problem with Greasemonkey is that the user can open up Chrome and then click People > Add Person and the extension is no longer in effect.

Comment: Change permissions on the browser's folder or user's profile folder, to make it read-only for the user. Allow bookmarks and other required files.

Comment: Oh interesting, like change permissions on their chrome instance so they can't spin up new profiles?

Comment: Set up a squid proxy...

Comment: What apps do you recommend for a squid proxy?

Comment: Yes, limit the permissions on some folders of the browser so they cannot create new profiles (usually a profile is a new folder) and even in their folders they are limited to bookmarks and especially cannot modify the extensions folder.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a solution, but it is tedious and might not work in really any case.

Notable, if you use a proxy that is able to do regex based replacement on html you can do it. We used mod_proxy_html within Apache in a reverse proxy situation for such things in the past. An alternative software is Burp from Portswigger - it has a regex replace function, one can restrict it to certain content types, it splices up SSL...
Routing your HTTP traffic through the proxy will resolve your point for all browsers behind it.

Having said this, please note:

- there is a performance penalty since going over the HTML string with a regex needs cpu
- the regex has to be very "stable" to cope with HTML variations for the same content
- the replacement needs to make sure not to break the surrounding HTML
- for SSL targets, the proxy needs to splice up the SSL connection; this requires the browsers to be configured with a "CA" cert that the proxy uses to create certificates on the fly (e.g. like Burp does); obviously this incurrs some privacy issues you have to evaluate for yourself

So you have been warned..

Answer (score 1):

Like most people have already mentioned, system-wide blocking of HTML elements (in all browsers) is not possible without using a proxy server (which will cause performance and reliability issues and also, security issues with SSL websites), my answer deals with the second part of the question -

> It will only work on the browser that I set up the rule with for the ad blocking tool and, even then, it's really easy for someone to get around the rule by disabling the extension.

Many browsers allow you to forcefully install an extension for all user profiles in an operating system and for all profiles created in the browser.

### [Firefox ESR/Enterprise](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/enterprise/)

(Since you tagged your qustion with [`firefox`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox))

1. You can follow [this knowledge-base article](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/deploying-firefox-with-extensions) to deploy certain extensions for all Firefox users on the PC.
2. Additionally, you can prevent users from disabling or removing that extension by ["`lock`"-ing it](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#extensions) by enforcing policies [using policies.json](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customizing-firefox-using-policiesjson) or [using GPO](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customizing-firefox-using-group-policy-windows) if you're using Windows.

### [Google Chrome Enterprise](https://chromeenterprise.google/)

(Since you showed interest in Chrome in [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1565089/#comment2389059_1565089))

- [Google Chrome Enterprise can be managed](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188446) either by applying policies from the cloud (Admin console with G Suite) or using on-premise tools and policy files. If you only want to set some policies for some devices manually, you don't need to use cloud management, but you can always choose whatever is best for you.
  Also, read more about applying policies to Chrome [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9037717).
- Refer to [this guide](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9296680) to get familiarised with all the options available in managing extensions using policies. For example, there are [policies](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/#extensions) that can help you *force-install* extension(s).
- You can disable the option to add new user profiles in Chrome using the [*BrowserAddPersonEnabled* policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=BrowserAddPersonEnabled).
- If you don't want to deploy Chrome Enterprise on a new system, you can simply add the policies to an existing system where Chrome is already installed -

  1. [Download the Chrome Enterprise Bundle](https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download) for Windows (since it contains the required policy files for all platforms).
  2. Follow Google's available instructions for enforcing policies on your platform - [for Windows](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7649838), [for Mac](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9020077) and [for Linux](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9027408).
  3. Restart Chrome and visit `chrome://policy` to verify that the policy has been applied.

Although, these options come close to the original query, this isn't a foolproof solution, because the users can always install another browser on your computer, or simply use their own device (phone or computer) over your connection to browse the website, if you somewhat block the installation of other browsers.
A proxy can help you modify a particular webpage for all devices on the connection, but users can switch to their own proxy or VPN or use a public proxy or VPN to browse the unmodified website.

Comment: I'd rather do something with policies than use a proxy. Can you please append this to include instructions for how to prevent the creation of new users in Google Chrome? Also-- do I need to pay or get a different install for GC Enterprise? (FWIW< Firefox and Firefox Enterprise are the same software install and I can use policies out the box)

Comment: @Cauder I have updated the answer to include the policy to prevent the creation of new user profiles in Chrome. I am not exactly sure but you shouldn't have to pay to simply apply policies to Chrome on a computer manually. You might need to pay if you're going to use [_Chrome Browser Cloud Management_](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9116814) though.

Comment: I'm awarding this answer because it's both excellent and exactly answers the question

Comment: Glad I could help : )

Answer (score 0):

Since most connections nowadays are `https` you woulnd't be able to open the packet and remove a specific html element unless you use a well featured proxy.

Basically the proxy would have to open the packet and remove the html element.

Go with [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin) for the win!

Comment: Would pi hole work as a proxy?

Comment: Raspberry PI ad blocking is not different from running a proxy on your own system. It *is* possible but you must love C++ developing. As I wrote: Basically the proxy would have to open the packet and remove the html element.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to get a content blocker and add the URLs of the
items to be blocked into its blacklist.

An example is the free
[uBlock Origin add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/)
where you may also use wildcards in the URLs to be blocked.
It comes with its own extensive list of websites that serve ads and other content
that is better avoided.

As most routers are based on Linux that has a much more evolved firewall than
Windows, you may be able to access Linux in your router, or install in it an
evolved firmware such as DD-WRT which allows complete control.
For this, you can use `iptables` tools and `Netfilter` firewall.

Getting an advanced firewall for Windows requires third-party software.
An example here is
[Comodo Free Antivirus with Internet Security](https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/free-internet-security.php)
whose firewall accepts URLs with wildcards.
Comodo is mostly free but some features need to be paid for.
See the article
[Block/allow Websites Selectively to Users of Your Computer](https://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-522-6408-.html).

Comment: Thanks for the windows solutions, I'm on Mac fwiw

Comment: uBlock Origin is browser extension, so system agnostic. The Mac may also have an evolved firewall.